# OpenMP with MPI- accessing array values which is available only to Master process

Tags: openmp, reduction

Say I have an array which is initialized in the Master process (rank=0) and contains random integers.

I want to sum all its (the array) elements by a Slave process (rank=1) when the full array is only available to the Master process (meaning I can't just MPI_SEND the full array to the slave).

I know I can use schedule in order to divide the work between multiple threads, but I'm not sure how to do it without sending the whole array to the Slave process.

Also, I've been checking different clauses while trying to solve the problem and came across REDUCTION, I'm not sure exactly how it works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is indeed a reduction with sum as the operation. Here is how a reduction works: You have a collection of items and an operation you wish to perform that *reduces* them to a single item. For example, you want to sum every element in an array and end with a single number that is their sum.

To do this efficiently you divide your collection into equal sized chunks and distribute them to each participating process. Each process applies the operation to the elements in the collection until the process has a single value. In our running example, each process adds together its chunk of the array. Then half the processes send their results to another node which then applies the operation to the value it computed and the value it received. At this point only half the original processes are participating. We repeat this until one process has the final result.

Here is a link to a graphic that should make this a lot easier to understand:  http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ybPe3bJrpgc/UzCoG9BUFuI/AAAAAAAAB2U/Jz6UcwV_Urk/s1600/TreeStructure.JPG

Here is some MPI code for a reduction: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/samples/C/mpi_array.c

Comment: Hey, thanks. 
Is it possible to do this with only 2 processes? when the slave uses multi threading and sends the answer back to the master? without sending the whole array to the Slave?

Comment: You can split the work between the slave and the master and have each sum half of it. You cannot have the slave sum the entire array without sending the entire array to the slave.